# One sample ttest pvalue in dplyr summarise_each

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

I would like to calculate a few summary statistics and the one sample ttest p value for various groups in a dataframe.

I was able to obtain the mean, max, min, count etc., but could not get the pvalue

Here is the code that worked with out the one sample ttest

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(nlmeU)

data(armd0, package = "nlmeU")
df <- armd0 %>%
  group_by(treat.f, time.f) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean, median, min, max, length, sd), visual)
```

I would like to obtain the output of t.test$p.value in the same table.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one sample t-test that the mean of the group is not 0, you can use `t.test` directly in `funs`, pulling out the p-value with dollar sign notation.  You'll need to give the new column a nicer name, though.

```
summarise_each(funs(mean, median, min, max, length, sd, pvalue = t.test(.)$p.value), visual)
```